The object continues to receive light from the turned off (through the light linking) light source
If you add an object to the light linking and turn it off, it stops receiving light from the turned off object, but receives it (light) as reflected rays from another object. Is there any way to turn this off with the light linking, or do I have to resort to some shading trickery? Any option will suit me.

 (Blender v 4.1.1)
